# permutation formula for leetcode 552. Student Attendance Record II

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have never asked on the Math stackexchange before and I don't know what's the culture and norm for asking question. Hopefully, my question is not too far a way from the norm here.

The question I have is about the permutation formula

$P(n,r)= \dfrac{n!}{(n−r)!}$

there is a leetcode (where programmers are practicing their coding skill for programming interview) problem. I have seen people solved it in different ways but I don't see them solve it with a formula. I am thinking if there is a Math formula for that.

Here is the problem https://leetcode.com/problems/student-attendance-record-ii/

I would love to see the Math formula for that I would like to to code that formula. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code with backtracking. It scale poorly to solve big n numbers. The code is pretty much standard for other permutation generating problem but this one is more of a math counting problem, I think.

```
class Solution:
"""
"""

def checkRecord(self, n):
    alp = "ALP"
    total = 0

    def backtracking(cur):
        nonlocal total

        if len(cur) == n:
            # print(cur)
            total += 1
            return

        for ch in alp:
            if ch == 'A' and cur.count('A'):
                continue
            if ch == 'L' and len(cur) >= 2 and cur[-2:] == ['L', 'L']:
                continue
            cur.append(ch)
            backtracking(cur)
            cur.pop()

    backtracking([])
    return total % (10 ** 9 + 7)
```

Comment: Is this an active competition?  It's hard to tell from the link.  If it is, you should wait for the contest to end before asking about it.

Comment: it is not a competition. it is where programmer practice their skill.  here are the discussion thread https://leetcode.com/problems/student-attendance-record-ii/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=   but I don't see the permutation formula approach.

Comment: Sure.  If I have understood the question, it is a simple exercise in [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Are you familiar with that technique

Comment: Alternatively, you can solve it by case work.  There are the cases with no $A's$ or $L's$, with one $A$ but no $L$, and so on.  Should be about the same amount of work.

Comment: I am sorry. I am not good with advanced Math. I am just a mere college drop out programmer ...

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  You don't solve a formula like this, you prove it is correct and use it in other problems.

Comment: This is not for a proof but it is to solve the coding brain teaser. I have coded it and solved it using backtracking (generating all the permutations) but it does not scale and I can only do n == 15 the most in time (well, I do n ==100 on my computer and it is running for over 3 our to solve it and still not finish, so  I just kill the program). A lot of other people has used Dynamic Programming approach but I don't see anyone solving it from the Math approach, thus I am asking to see if there can be a formula/equation like the standard permutation and then I will code to that equation to solv

Comment: Although we can produce a summation formula such as $$\sum_{\substack{0\leq l\leq n \\ 0 \leq c \leq l/2}}(n-l+1) \binom{n-l+1}{n-2l+c+1,l-2c,c}, $$ it is not particularly fact as it required $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ terms. I think a better idea is to set up a system of recurrence relations, which I believe has already been implemented in some of the solutions in the discussion tab.

Comment: ok, thanks. it seems that the summation formula provided is not as  straight forward as the standard permutation and it will be hard to remember. Yes, there has been some recurrence relation implementation. I just come here with the hope that if there can be simpler approach like permutation_of_this  subtract permutation_of_that_and_that. thanks tho.

Comment: Click edit to take a look at the MathJax I put in to format your question. You need to use this formatting to ask questions here.

Comment: thanks. I am not that familiar with the usage of that but I should have looked around and tried it out myself.